Use of Laplace Rule of Succession to predict chance of all heads in a biased coin
If I have a coin, which is known to be biased, Laplace's rule says that the probability the coin lands heads is (heads + 1)/(total flips + 2). If I flip this coin 100 times, the probability of the first head is 1/2, the second head is 2/3, since you observe a head in the first flip. 3/4 for the third head, because you observed two heads already, and so on, leading to a total probability of 1/101. This seems way too high, is there a flaw in my logic, or is the probability just much higher than expected?
Upon further inspection, it appears that the probability is indeed 1/101, since the integral $\int_{0}^{1} x^{100} dx$ evaluates to 1/101.
